# Sentinel 2 Surface reflectance Range

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I need to get a reasonable Sentinel 2 Surface reflectance using Google Earth Engine, I tried but the values are between 10000 - 0

```
var ReflectTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: temps2013,
  regions: westernRegions,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'label'
});

ReflectTimeSeries.setChartType('LineChart');
ReflectTimeSeries.setOptions({
  title: 'Sentinel 2 band values at three points near Potsdam City',
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Time Series'
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Reflectance (intensity)',
    Divide : 10000
  },
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 4,
  series: {
    0: {color: COLOR.PARK},
    1: {color: COLOR.FARM},
    2: {color: COLOR.URBAN}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

if you go through the documentation for Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-2A, it will show you that the bands have been scaled. There is scale of each band mentioned but for most of the standard bands that you want to work with it is 0.0001

so if you want red, green and blue bands you can essentially select those bands and rescale them using multiplication with scale.

```
var scaled = sentinel2image.select(['B4','B3','B2']).multiply(0.0001)
```

Of course you could divide by 10000 as well but I prefer multiply because then I can use the numbers mentioned in the documentation without having to do the mental math however easy that may be.

Now, as you want to apply this to all the images in the imagecollection you can use the **map** function in a similar way. However, for graphs you want to preserve the properties of the image, especially the **system:time_start**. For this you will need to copy the properties of original image onto the new rescaled image using **copyProperties** function.

```
var rescale = function(image){
  var rescaledImage = image.multiply(0.0001);
  return rescaledImage.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

s2 = s2.map(rescale)
```

A working example can be seen [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c37042ad34197e64671fb81ae870437)

Comment: But `multiply()` is not available for `imageCollection`, you need to use `map()`. How you keep metadata with this? `system:time_start` must be preserved for graphical purposes

Comment: you can preserve the original image details within the map by using copyProperties. I will edit my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: yes, now your answer is complete. Well done

Answer (score -2):

If you want reflectance value, then you need to do the atmospheric correction using Sen2cor to change DN value to reflectance value. 
I think (0 - 10000) value is DN value.